# Routing not working with dynamic URL

Tags: sapui5

See my code in Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/knuf4Z64Kla2vPQRociv?p=info

I am trying to get the routing part working with a dynamic URL.

my Component.js (only metadata, full code is in plnkr.co)

```js
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("com.myapp.Component", {
    metadata: {
        rootView: "myapp.main",
        routing: {
            config: {
                routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
                viewType: "JS",
                viewPath: "myapp",
                controlId: "mainapp",
                controlAggregation: "pages",
                transition: "slide"
            },
            routes: [{
                pattern: "main",
                name: "main",
                target: "main"
            }, {
                pattern: "agent",
                name: "agent",
                target: "agent"
            }],
            targets: {
                main: {
                    viewName: "main",
                    viewLevel: 1
                },
                agent: {
                    viewName: "agent",
                    viewLevel: 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/cf3c57c89ef0491793d1ce327ab4f9b2.html

You need to specify a `routerClass` in your config. That is most probably why router is `undefined` in your scenario.

Furthermore you will need to specify a `rootView` as well as a `controlId` and a `controlAggregation` in your routing config.

Comment: Hi @cschuff, can you please explain more, regarding my updated question. Thank you

Comment: Could you create a new rootView, place the App control in there and remove the createContent from the Component.js? I'm not totally sure if createContent and addPAges works well together with routing...